Sequence of instructions executed by CPU to retrieve data from NIC
In cases where no DMA is available for a peripheral device such as a Network Interface Card to directly send data from the onboard buffers to system memory, how is it handled? What sequence of instructions will the CPU execute to move the data from the onboard buffers all the way to system memory? Does it involve the data itself as immediate operands or just references to memory addresses?
I know this is more of a subjective question since each computer has different code but I am talking about in general (both x86 and ARM is valid)

Usually MMIO, which looks like reading the same memory address repeatedly.  Immediate operands are data that's part of the machine code, so that doesn't make sense unless the NIC had a buffer of machine code for the CPU to execute.  (It doesn't, it would just provide a buffer of data for the driver to memcpy if it was going to do that.)

https://wiki.osdev.org/Ne2000 has an example of a simple NIC, although it does DMA into the host's memory for the actual data, and it looks like the example is using port IO (IO address-space, not MMIO) to give it pointers and commands.

so essentially what it does is execute the same piece of code (the driver's memcpy) when new data needs to be transferred into system memory?

Yes, for a hypothetical NIC that had large buffer on the device instead of writing to system memory as packets are received.  Or it might have the data readable 4 or 8 bytes at a time from an MMIO register, like how non-DMA hard-drive controllers worked, where you repeatedly read the same address which is an MMIO register, which has a side-effect of advancing an internal pointer so the next read gets a different value.  (Although PIO mode ATA controllers were port IO with x86 instructions like in, so reading from IO address-space not memory address-space.)
